# Reflective generic type bounds and method chaining

Tags: java, generics

I need to provide a generic interface to be used in separate class hierarchies and would like that interface to support invocation chaining.

I have tried to do this using reflective bounds, but I can't seem to get it to work without having to cast "this" to the desired type. Here is my current approach:

```
public interface Operable<T extends Operable<T>> {
  T prepare();
  T operate();
}

public abstract class BaseOperable<T extends Operable<T>> implements Operable<T> {
  @Override
  public T prepare() {
    System.out.println("Preparing...");
    // why is this needed? "this" is a BaseOperable that implements Operable<T>
    return (T) this;
  }
}

public class SpecialOperable<T extends SpecialOperable<T>> extends
    BaseOperable<SpecialOperable<T>> {
  @Override
  public T operate() {
    System.out.println("Operation "
            + (Math.random() > 0.5 ? "succeeded" : "failed"));
    // this seems to be required
    return (T) this;
  }

  @Override
  public T prepare() {
    // if I don't override this, the supertype T is used which is
    // BaseOperable and hides "specialOp" from chaining
    return (T) super.prepare();
  }

  public T specialOp() {
    System.out.println("Doing something special...");
    return (T) this;
  }
}
```

The above the following line of code to compile:
`mySpecialOperable().prepare().operate().specialOp().operate();`

My question is: is there any way to avoid type-casting of every return statement? Is it also possible to not have to override everything at the most specialized level (as is done with the `prepare()` method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming type safety at a place where the compiler cannot determine at compile-time if a casting is legal. This entails the warning you encounter: For making this more clear, assume:

```
class Foo implements Operable<Foo> { ... } // legal
class Bar implements Operable<Foo> { ... } // not intended, but also legal
```

The `Bar` class is not intended to be legal by your abstraction model. You want to implement a *self-type* but all you can factually require in Java is to demand the extension of a type `T` that implements a given interface. Thus, extending

```
class Bar extends BaseOperable<Foo> { ... }
```

would basically be executed at run time as if you implemented:

```
class Bar implements Operable<Foo> {
  @Override
  public Foo prepare() {
    System.out.println("Preparing...");
    // Why is this needed, you ask? Because you are now expressing this:
    return (Foo) this; // this is of type Bar, not Foo
  }
  ...
}
```

where `this` is however an instance of `Bar` but not of `Foo`. This, of course, causes a `ClassCastException` and for this possibility, the compiler warns you that static type-safety has failed you and this exception might happen where you would not normally expect it.

You normally avoid this by adding a method like:

```
protected abstract T self();
```

which is then implemented by any non-abstract class. As this method is then implemented with a non-generic return type, the static compile check can do its work and forbid you any illegal return types as we observed before. The above `prepare` method would then be implemented like this:

```
public T prepare() {
  System.out.println("Preparing...");
  return self();
}
```

If you are however working with a closed API that is not implemented by any user and you want to take that short cut (hopefully, you have unit tests that validate against any possible abuse), you can annotate the method with `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` to tell the compiler that you are aware of what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simplified to:

```
public abstract class AbstractOperable<T extends AbstractOperable<T>> {

    public T prepare() {
        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from AbstractOperable<T> to T
        return this;
    }

}

public class OperableImpl extends AbstractOperable<OperableImpl> {

}
```

Now, consider the following class:

```
public class OperableImplHack extends AbstractOperable<OperableImpl> {

}
```

While it fulfills the `T extends AbstractOperable<T>` contract, `this` is not `T`. This is the reason why the compiler can't know if `this` is `T` or not in `AbstractOperable`.

---

Solution #1:

```
public abstract class AbstractOperable<T extends AbstractOperable<T>> {

    public abstract T getThis();

    public T prepare() {
        return getThis();
    }

}

public class OperableImpl extends AbstractOperable<OperableImpl> {

    @Override
    public OperableImpl getThis() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Solution #2:

```
public abstract class AbstractOperable<T extends AbstractOperable<T>> {

    protected T that;

    public T prepare() {
        return that;
    }

}

public class OperableImpl extends AbstractOperable<OperableImpl> {

    public OperableImpl() {
        that = this;
    }

}
```